How to make a request to the OpenAI API?
I'm getting an authentication error when using my API key that I created at OpenAI.com to make a request.
This is the code that I used:
from openai import OpenAI

client = OpenAI(api_key = "Lkey")

response = client.completions.create(
    model = "gpt-3.5-turbo-instruct",
    prompt = "What is OpenAI?"
)

print(response)

Even though I created an API key at OpenAI.com, I get an error that the key doesn't exist instead of having the completion object:

AuthenticationError: Error code: 401 - {'error': {'message': 'Incorrect API key provided: Lkey. You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.', 'type': 'invalid_request_error', 'param': None, 'code': 'invalid_api_key'}}

I tried it in VS Code with all extensions and online editors but nothing works.

Are you certain Lkey is replaced when u run the script?

Lkey is the name of my api key

Either you pass the value of that key directly as u do right now (instead of LKey) or you set it in the system as a variable as described here https://platform.openai.com/docs/quickstart/step-2-set-up-your-api-key . It does not matter what you name the key in the OpenAI platform, all you need is the value. Name is just for you information.

When you say ''the value of the key" do you mean the secrete key sk-****?

Yes, that key value is your credential to authenticate against OpenAI API and consume its services. It does not know what Key Name you chose there, since you are not authenticated yet, your script needs that key value to authenticate first. Name is irrelevant.

I tried it again using the secrete key, first by adding it without the sk- part and i got this error that my key is invalide, and another atempte by adding the sk- part and i got an error saying that i have insufficient_quota

insufficient_quota is different error and it is not problem with code but you may have to pay for more quota

when I login to OpenAI webpage then it shows limits for different models and turbo-instruct on Free Trial has limits 3 requests per minute, and 200 requests per day - 3 RPM 200 RPD. And billing shows how many money you still have for running it. As I remember at start they give $5 for Free trial but later you have to pay on your own.

in that case, what can i do to keep learning?

Have you set up the API key in the environment variables?
If you haven't tried yet, you can set up the API key in the environment variables with the following command:
`export API_KEY=your_API_key_here`

Also
`response = client.completions.create` 

this code could be making the error, so if the command doesn't work, you can also try this code
`response = openai.chat.completions.create`

I hope it is helpful.

Exporting the variable wouldn't be read automatically in the code
